# Error: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm copy pasting one of the examples from here:

https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

**HTML:**

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{ option }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

**TS:**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {startWith} from 'rxjs/operators/startWith';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators/map';

/**
 * @title Filter autocomplete
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'autocomplete-filter-example',
  templateUrl: 'autocomplete-filter-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['autocomplete-filter-example.css']
})
export class AutocompleteFilterExample {

  myControl: FormControl = new FormControl();

  options = [
    'One',
    'Two',
    'Three'
  ];

  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(val => this.filter(val))
      );
  }

  filter(val: string): string[] {
    return this.options.filter(option =>
      option.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0);
  }

}
```

**CSS:**

```
.example-form {
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}

.example-full-width {
  width: 100%;
}
```

But I get this error:

> Failed to compile: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

Any idea why?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with the `.pipe()`? The docs here seem to suggest that method is for converting a sequence into a Node.js stream? https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_instance_methods/pipe.html

Comment: @joshrathke I'm just following the tutorial and copying the code, not sure what that's supposed to do as I;m still brand new to Angular in general.

Answer (score 2):

> Please check for the RxJS version compatibility.
>
> As i did go through you code and found correct and working. Kindly see
>   for the `version of RxJS should be > 5.5`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are usingthe latest version of rxjs@5.x.x and angular.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md

Answer (score 0):

I found issue in your code i.e

```
myControl: FormControl = new FormControl();
```

Remove 'FormControl' from this line. Actually you are defining its 'Type' but this doesn't exist for 'new FormControl()', I am wondering why 'tslint' not giving error in your code. Anyway see again https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview , here angular also not using like the code you have pasted here.

Answer (score 0):

may be For the .pipe method to be available because of the miss match of versioning

this one works for me

```
remove the node modules and reinstall the packages (npm i)
```

Answer (score -2):

Based on your comments above it seems like you are just trying to subscribe to the value changes that occur on that FormControl. Try this:

```js
this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
    .subscribe(_Changes => {
        console.log(_Changes);
    }
```

Not exactly sure what your intent is here, but this should at least start spitting the change values out at you.